# Pacman unable to update since it breaks dependency with itself

Tags: linux, arch-linux, updates, pacman

I tried to update my Arch system today and pacman is trying to update itself, and is unable to do so due to dependancy breaking.
The error is this:

```
    :: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                                133,9 KiB   542K/s 00:00 [#######################################################] 100%
 extra                                                              1644,6 KiB   392K/s 00:04 [#######################################################] 100%
 community                                                             4,9 MiB   485K/s 00:10 [#######################################################] 100%
 multilib                                                            169,3 KiB   576K/s 00:00 [#######################################################] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace ilmbase with extra/openexr? [Y/n] y
warning: liblastfm-qt5: local (1.1.0.r637-4) is newer than extra (1.0.9-4)
warning: python2-mutagen: local (1.42.0-3) is newer than antergos (1.38-2)
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing pacman (5.2.0-2) breaks dependency 'pacman<5.2' required by pamac
```

Any sugestions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the `pamac` package actually comes from.

- When a third-party binary repository package (Antergos and Manjaro both count as 'third-party') has a versioned dependency on a standard Arch package:

  1. Cancel the update and wait for the repository to get a new version, with the dependencies updated. (There already is pamac v9.0.2 with support for pacman 5.2 so it shouldn't take long.)
- When an AUR package (which you compiled with makepkg yourself), or a package that is *no longer* in the binary repositories, has a versioned dependency on a repository package:

  1. Remove the AUR package.
  2. Upgrade the system as usual.
  3. Reinstall the latest version of the AUR package, making sure to rebuild it even if you already had the built package cached.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have an Antergos system, so I guess I will wait a bit and then accept the answer as solution if it gets resolved.

Comment: Having the same issue myself (on Antergos)

Comment: Antergos is no more, so I don't expect their repos will see much updating, is there a simple way to switch which depository that pamac is installed from?

Comment: Pacman doesn't care which repository it's installing a package from, as long as it's among the enabled repositories. However, your main problem would be that there _is_ no repository with pamac in it. In that case, you would follow the 2nd set of instructions (remove, upgrade, reinstall from AUR).

Comment: For antergos gnome you must remove these beforehand 'sudo pacman -R pamac antergos-gnome-meta'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning.  (It's not that pacman has a dependency on itself, it's that there's an older version of **pamac** that has a dependency requiring an older version of **pacman**.)

I resolved it by:

1. Uninstalling my pamac-related packages so they don't block upgrading pacman

```
sudo pacman -R pamac-gtk-dev pamac-cli-dev pamac-common-dev
```

2. Then doing the system upgrade

```
sudo pacman -Syuu
```

3. Then reinstalling those pamac packages (this time to the latest versions)

```
sudo pacman -S pamac-gtk-dev pamac-cli-dev pamac-common-dev
```